# mongodb, pymongo querying

Tags: python, mongodb

I've been browsing through the documentation, but I can't seem to figure out a way to perform a find on my mongodb collection using only a key.
For example, let's suppose this is what's inside my collection

```
{ 'res1': 10 }
{ 'res2: 20 }
```

How can I query the collection using only the key 'res1', in order to get 10 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure exaclty what you want, so... This is if you want all documents that have key res1 set:

`db.collection.find({'res1': { $exists : true }})`

And this is if you want all the documents that have key res1 set to 10:

`db.collection.find({'res1': 10})`

Answer (score 2):

Ah, I guess I'm structuring my data all wrong, I should have something like this:

```
{ 'name': 'res1',
  'value': 10 }
```

Right?

Comment: Right - you can also use a fields specifier to get back only the value portion:

`db.collection.find({'name': 'res1'}, fields=['value'])`

Answer (score 1):

```
> db.collection.find({'res1': 10}) # Returns a cursor.
```

In your case, find_one method will do the needful.

```
> db.collection.find_one({'res1': 10}) # Returns a document whose value is 10
```